# Create Azure Funtcion From ARM whit custom Function App Edit Mode

Tags: azure-devops

I have an ARM template with a section with a function app, and I deploy all I need, except this parameter. I need to set in read / write mode, but I can not find how to do. I don't find the property. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to set FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE to readwrite as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings

Therefore you probably need something like this in your ARM json…

```
"appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE",
          "value": "readwrite"
        }]
```

Hope that helps,
Colin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didin't found the documentation.